# Issue Trying to Sort by Date

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I'm trying to sort on a form which happens to be a Continuous Form on a main form. Also, the default sort order is to Sort by Descending date on opening the form.

I tried to remove the default sort order. I also tried to sort it in a query or datasheet view and it worked fine.

The code for this is:

```
DoCmd.GoToControl "ActionDate"
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFilterMenu
```

It sorts the `ActionDate` but with the message:

> The object doesn't contain the Automation object 'Category'.
>
> You tried to run a Visual Basic procedure to set a property or method for an object. However, the component doesn't make the property or method available for Automation operations. Check the component's documentation for information on the properties and methods it makes available for Automation operations.

Please help!

Comment: The error message seems to have nothing to do with posted code. What event is code in? Is there more? Cross post http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=77031

Comment: The code is in the OnClick event of the button

Comment: +1 to @June7. Button is placed on main form, right? So, to my mind, how are you addressing the subform to be sorted?

Comment: Thanks!! But actually the button is placed on the subform.

Comment: Check your Link Master and Child Fields properties in the SubForm control in the parent form.

Comment: Would you please elaborate on this? I can't see the Master and Child Fields properties?